# Bootstrap layout: How to have an aside with columns underneath

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am forced to put an ad to the right of my content in the box that says 350x400.
The problem is that those columns to the right really should be two rows with 2 videos, but they are 2 columns with two videos instead. Because i wasn't sure how to have the ad to the right without using 2 size 3 cols and 1 size 6 col.

the problem comes with the text is long and jumps to the new line. On the top 4 videos it breaks things, on the bottom ones it works great (because they are proper rows)
[image: pic that works]

[image: broken pic]

Does anyone know a good way to handle this case? or is it just not something bootstrap is capable of as of now.

Thanks,
Sammy
REAL-CODE: https://gist.github.com/kekeoki/14bd0004cbd76a0c0571da2d841d7883
Kinda Similar fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31225/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    Wow sick ad check it out
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-push-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Most Relevant Video Results: "Keyword"</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="thumbnail row text-center" style="min-height:260px;">
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300" style="height:200px;  background: url(/public/img/loading.gif) 50% no-repeat;">
                      <h5>text</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="thumbnail row text-center" style="min-height:260px;">
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300" style="height:200px;  background: url(/public/img/loading.gif) 50% no-repeat;">
                      <h5>text</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="thumbnail row text-center" style="min-height:260px;">
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300" style="height:200px;  background: url(/public/img/loading.gif) 50% no-repeat;">
                      <h5>text</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="thumbnail row text-center" style="min-height:260px;">
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300" style="height:200px;  background: url(/public/img/loading.gif) 50% no-repeat;">
                      <h5>text</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class=" row thumbnail text-center">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x400">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail row text-center" style="min-height:260px;">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300" style="height:200px;  background: url(/public/img/loading.gif) 50% no-repeat;">
                  <h5>text</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail row text-center" style="min-height:260px;">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300" style="height:200px;  background: url(/public/img/loading.gif) 50% no-repeat;">
                  <h5>text</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail row text-center" style="min-height:260px;">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300" style="height:200px;  background: url(/public/img/loading.gif) 50% no-repeat;">
                  <h5>text</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail row text-center" style="min-height:260px;">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300" style="height:200px;  background: url(/public/img/loading.gif) 50% no-repeat;">
                  <h5>text</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Related Searches</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          Panel content
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Categories</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          Panel content
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Stuff</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 ">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Other content or ad</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          content here
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="row text-center">
        paginate
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Other content or ad</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          content here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show us your code (preferably in a code snippet or jsfiddle) so we can help!

Comment: @AJFunk done! thanks I use golang template so it is hard to make a fiddle

Comment: fiddle looks good. I see what you mean about the long text, but I don't understand when you say "The problem is that those columns to the right really should be two rows with 2 videos, but they are 2 columns with two videos instead."

Comment: @AJFunk if i was able to make two rows like this - -  ad
                                                                              - - ad
they would scale appropriately, but they have to be columns to get it to work